# How to dynamically construct a file path string in CMakeLists?

Tags: cmake

Given a file path `engine/*`, how would one append every filename into allheader.h so it looked like this:

```
#include engine/foo.h
#include engine/faa.h
#include engine/engine.h
etc.
```

My current CMakeList attempt is as so, but this results in #include file(RELATIVE_PATH)

```
foreach(file ${ENGINE})
    file(APPEND allheader.h " #include ")
    file(APPEND allheader.h file(RELATIVE_PATH))
endforeach()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a function inside a function i.e. `foo(... bar(...))` won't work, so first compute the local "PATH" then use it.

I would try:

```
foreach(FILE ${ENGINE})
    file(RELATIVE_PATH PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} ${FILE})
    file(APPEND allheader.h "#include \"${PATH}\"")
endforeach()
```

ref: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#relative-path

Comment: You still need to quote the include path: `file(APPEND allheader.h "#include \"${PATH}\"")`